# How to correct "Instance has failed unhealthy threshold number of health checks " in my target group of application Load balancer?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cloud, amazon-elb

I created my second instance using my first instance using "Create more like this", but my second instance is failing health checks even after my first instance has passed health check. What should I do to correct this error so that I can add multiple instances in my target group using load balancer?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XkYch.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you click `Create more like this` you're creating a duplicate of the base AWS settings.

Any configuration done on top of the base AMI, such as package installation or code deployments will not be on your new instance. Make sure these are done before  adding to the load balancer.

If you want to take an actual clone of the first instance then look at [creating an AMI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/creating-an-ami-ebs.html), and then launching from that instead.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This time first I created one instance, created its image, and created my second instance using the AMI. Afterward, I added both of my instances in the target group and they both passed the health check.

Comment: Glad I could help with resolving this :)